# Start one thread per each Method in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm interested to have multiple threads in a program, and my requirement is to start up each method in a new thread.

Suppose I have the following:

```
public class A
{
  int val=0;

  public void foo() 
  {
    for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
    { 
      val=j;
      Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
  }

  public int boo()
  {  
    return val;
  }
}
```

I want to create an object in this class in a separate class like this

```
public class B
{
  A myA = new A();
  myA.foo();
  int ret=myA.boo();
}
```

What i want is, when u call `foo()` and `boo()`, those two methods will have to run on separate threads. So i can use the updated value of `"val"` from the `boo()` method.

Please be kind enough to give me some advices to overcome this problem.
Thanks in advance..:)

Comment: extend `Thread`, and implement in `run()`. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Comment: like mentioned, use the docs to see how to use threads. Since you want to run method from same class on different threads.. you might want to add a condition , like name of thread , to  execute method.

Comment: Can i use two run() methods..? Because i want to execute foo() and boo() in two seperate methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can run your code on a new Thread using the following:

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            //do stuff here
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: Thanks lrAndroid, But i need to clarify the fact that how to use run() method to execute two seperate methods executed by two seperate threads

Comment: You start a new Thread from both foo() and boo().  Thus the above code will actually appear twice in your class (once running the foo code, and again with the boo code).

Comment: So how the each run() methods know who called run(), either foo() or boo()..?

Comment: The new Thread(new Runnable...) code will be inside the foo and boo methods.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (the simplest possible example):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final A myA = new A();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            myA.foo();
        }).start();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            int ret=myA.boo();
        }).start();

    Thread.sleep(9999);

}
```

You need to make `A` `final` because that's the deal with anonymous classes (like the two `Runnables` in the example) accessing local variables.

Also, you have to add `volatile` to `val` (otherwise the other thread may not see any changes to it):

```
volatile int val = 0;
```